# Parsing JSON (?) response from Facebook SDK iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm tearing my hair out. I'm using the Facebook SDK in an iOS application to request the score of a player. The response I get looks like this when output to the console:

```
{
     data =     (
                {
            application =             {
                id = 790595290993938;
                name = "Laser Blast";
            };
            score = 100;
            user =             {
                id = 10152606174287397;
                name = "Chris Koncewicz";
            };
        }
     );
}
```

How do I get the value for the score? I've tried making an `NSDictionary` using:

```
NSDictionary *d = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

However, I can't see how to access the score value.

Any help greatly appreciated.

### EDIT:

This is the code snippet that runs the request and where I'm trying to work with the response:

```
[getScore startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"%@", result);
NSDictionary *d = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result options:kNilOptions error:&error];
}];
```

Comment: Don't add more code in a comment. Update your question with the relevant code so people can read it.

Comment: The output you have has already been parsed.  It's a dictionary containing an array that contains a dictionary that contains two dictionaries and a "score" value.  Learn how to read NSLog dumps!!!

Comment: Thanks Hot Licks - the reason I put a ? after JSON in the title was because it didn't match the format I thought it would be in for JSON. If I was able to work this out I wouldn't have had to resort to posting on here.

Comment: Like I said, it's already been parsed -- into dictionaries and arrays.  The way that Nslog dumps dictionaries and arrays is *almost* like the corresponding JSON format, but not quite.  `( )` is an array, `{ }` is a dictionary, purely alphabetic strings are shown without quotes.

Comment: Thanks - apologies if i came across as being rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might overlooked the fact numbers are stored as `NSNumber` objects in collections:

```
NSInteger score = facebookJson[@"data"][0][@"score"].integerValue;
```

Comment: More the fact that I didn't know to reference @"data" from the NSDictionary, element [0] and then the key @"score". I'd missed the [0] out. Thank you